# How to present hierarchical data in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, treeview

What is the best way to display hierarchical data in iPhone application?

Do you know some TreeView controls for iPhone?

Answer (score 8):

Question is a little bit old but as I was searching for something similar I though it's good to add the reference in case others need.

You may want to have a look here [Rolling your own iPhone treeview control](http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=656). That is the summary article that point to single articles (4 in total).

Code is available [here](https://github.com/LaTtEX/MyTreeViewPrototype)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you would use a series of UITableView's combined with a UINavigationController. I'll see if I can find a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could try treeview-4iphone

http://code.google.com/p/treeview-4iphone/

Although there's no package to download you can get out the source via svn (you'll need to click on "source" tab).